# Coaxing a browser to issue an If-Range get request

Tags: asp.net, http

I'm trying to implement range request functionality on a page based on [Scott Mitchell's](https://web.archive.org/web/20110303000025/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/ScottMitchell.shtml) example.  The problem that I'm having is that the browsers that I'm using (IE9 and Firefox 11) don't seem to issue an If-Range request no matter how I interrupt the download.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox, simply pausing and resuming the download **in the download manager** will issue a request with **If-Match** and **Range** headers.

Comment: Under the same circumstances, IE 9 will use If-Range (instead of If-Match).  Strange.